# Clustering documents based on pairwise similarity and without access to features

Tags: clustering, hierarchical-clustering

I have a set of documents and distances among them. I want to cluster the documents based on pairwise distances/similarities among them.

I have only a single parameter as distance. What are the available clustering algorithms to work on these kind of problems?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "correlation distance".

Comment: correlation distances means distance between every two nodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that you only have access to pairwise distances among your documents but no access to the documents themselves, there are still some clustering techniques you can apply.

Algorithms like k-Means, which require access to the feature space (e.g., to place the centroids) cannot be applied. However, scikit-learn has some other clustering algorithms which can work by simply analyzing a matrix of pairwise distances among samples:

- [AffinityPropagation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation.html#sklearn.cluster.AffinityPropagation), with the option affinity="precomputed"
- [SpectralClustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.SpectralClustering), again with affinity="precomputed"
- [AgglomerativeClustering](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering.html#sklearn.cluster.AgglomerativeClustering), passing affinity="precomputed"
- [DBSCAN](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN.html#sklearn.cluster.DBSCAN), with metric="precomputed"

edit: Take a look at the concerns of @Anony-Mousse in the comments to this answer.

Comment: Note that affinity requires different input than distance metrics.

Comment: @Anony-Mousse, can you be more specific? I can edit the answer if I am missing something.

Comment: Some methods require a *similarity*, some a *distance*. That is not the same.

Comment: Well, I checked and all the cited clustering methods from sklearn accept euclidean distances. I will remove the "or some other similarity measure" from the answer, as maybe some weird custom similarities might cause problems with some of the algorithms. Thanks for the correction.

Comment: Try passing a precomputed Euclidean distance matrix to these functions vs. passing the data matrix and setting the parameter to run euclidean. You'll see that for the first two you get fundamentally different results, only the bottom two expect a distance matrix k (to make it more confusing, the "affinity" parameter of AC does *not* expect an affinity but a distance matrix).

Comment: Well, If that is the case, maybe it would be good to open an issue about this in the sklearn repo. I will look into that more carefully if I have the time.